# Is there a new auto-login feature?

Tags: discussion, login, linked-accounts

I just noticed something interesting: once I log in to any one Stack Exchange site, if I go to another Stack Exchange site where I have an account, I'll automatically get logged in without having to click "log in" and enter my OpenID. I see the "Welcome to Q&A..." banner pop up and then a second later, the page gets reloaded and I see my account information at the top. Is this a new feature of the SE network? (Or has it been around for a while and I just haven't been paying attention?)

**EDIT**: It doesn't seem to happen with Super User...

Comment: Ah, I just switched to Chromium recently; I was giving it credit for doing some kind of black magic to make that happen

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, we are testing this feature now.

Comment: Do you have to have logged into the site at least once before?

Comment: @ChrisF - you must have an account on the site, so yes technically.

Comment: I'm sure people will find reasons to complain about this feature, but for now, I like it :-)

Comment: @Kevin - I wasn't sure whether it would automatically create and associate an account, so I thought I ought to check. I know creating a new account is different type of action to logging in and so not something you'd necessarily automate, but you might if you wanted to ease people's flow around the sites.

Comment: @ChrisF - account auto-creation was considered, but quickly decided that its better if you explicitly join a community rather than have membership thrust upon you.  So to speak.

Comment: That welcome banner was missing the word, "Kotter".

Comment: @random - wow, that went off the air almost a decade before I was born.

Comment: @Jeff is that what http://stackauth.com is for?

Comment: @Kevin - good decision I think.

Comment: @Kevin Is there any other requirements besides needing an account? I have an associated SU account but it's not logging me in. My assumption is that it is because I'm only logged in via cookie, not an active OpenId provider session. Is this the case?

Comment: @Grace Note - you must be registered (and have a common OpenId between the two sites), and there are some browser and timing requirements.  The whole scheme is still being worked on, so the details are... fluid.