# How does SO's new auto-login feature work without any refresh?

Tags: discussion, login, auto-login, implementation

[How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work)

The above link talks about how auto login is implemented in SO. Answer to that post points to this solution.

[Is there a new auto-login feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62005/is-there-a-new-auto-login-feature)

Now in 2016, if i access another SO site after logging into one, we get logged into the second site immediately without any page refresh.

I am curious to know how this "without any page refresh" login thing work.

Comment: This is announced [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login): "When you log into any Q&A site on the stackexchange.com domain, you will be automatically logged into all other Q&A sites on the stackexchange.com domain + stackexchange.com itself" - however, it does not explain the "how" part, so leaving this open in hope it will be explained.

Answer (score 17):

Back in 2015, we [announced a redesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login) of the login system. It's been running for a few months now and seems to be doing alright.

When you log in, we issue a cookie for the second-level domain of the site you're logging into. If you only ever visit the sites based off of stackexchange.com, there's nothing special here. It's just that the auth cookie has `.stackexchange.com` as its domain, so it's accessible on all sites that share it. (Previously, each site set its own cookie at its own subdomain.)

Things get a bit more interesting when we want to log someone in on stackexchange.com *and* stackoverflow.com *and* serverfault.com, etc. We have seven of such domains in total.

If we were Google or a similarly large site, this would possibly be easier. They can afford to bounce you through several domains during sign-in (which is how you end up logged into, say, Gmail and Youtube at the same time) without a substantial performance penalty. We don't have that luxury. Our data centers are too far away from a lot of our users to provide a not-massively-annoying sign-in experience. So we do the next best thing - issue an "image" request to other domains. This request includes validation measures to prevent random/malicious requests from bad actors, but ultimately it is just an attempt to load a 1px transparent .gif that actually comes back with a `Set-Cookie` header. If the request is validated, we set the auth cookie on the domain that did the validation... effectively logging you in there.

This doesn't work in a few cases - in Safari (which rejects all third-party cookies no matter what), or if the user explicitly disables third-party cookies. It also doesn't work for [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) despite it sharing the domain with a bunch of Q&A sites. This is because A51 is a completely separate codebase that doesn't have direct access to the database that keeps track of the account sessions. I have some ideas on how we could make the sign-in experience there more seamless, but I need to set some time free to try them out and see what happens.

Anyway, that's about it. Hope this helps; let me know if there's anything you'd like me to elaborate more on.

Comment: 6 years ago, Kevin said "A browser as popular as Safari just plain not working with any third-party cookie scheme just kills the entire technology for us." So what changed there? Do you just view the % of Safari users as negligible now? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64274/161554

Comment: @andrewtweber Yes and no. I don't know what the % was six years ago, but when we looked at it again, the pros of this approach (such as allowing us to support SSL - we need to move meta sites to \*.meta.stackexchange.com, so the old "meta sites have access to the parent site's cookie" scheme wouldn't work either) outweigh the potential inconvenience to Safari visitors and anyone else who deliberately turns off third-party cookies. A common case is still "log in once, log into all \*.stackexchange.com" sites, and most people don't have accounts on *all* SLDs we have.

Comment: Ah that's true, at most they have the inconvenience of logging into ~5 domains now instead of 100. That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I use Safari, and I just posted https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361041/better-integration-or-separation-between-so-se-sites-in-different-domains on this.  ODDLY, when I went to Travel after, it DID log me in again!  Since third-party cookies are a rather obnoxious tracking method, I suspect that could easily be stated "outweigh the potential inconvenience to a heck of a lot of people."